# Destination of navigation back button swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I connected UITableViews with `Show` segue. I want to change some variable of destination tableView whenever I tap the Back button on navigation bar. Let's say I'm not allowed to create a new back button, how can I detect/call the destination tableView when the back button is tapped? Like in prepareforsegue we have segue.destination, is there some thing like "backbutton.destination"?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this? If not... can you please respond to my questions in the comments on my answer. I would like to help but can’t if you don’t offer any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing here (I think) is not trying to find the destination of the back button but passing in the interested object when going forwards.

On you detail view you could have something like...

```
protocol DetailViewDelegate {
    func detailViewDidChange()
}
```

Then in the detail view controller...

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: DetailViewDelegate?

    // you could call this from viewWillDisappear or something
    func doThisWhenYouWantToUpdateTheTableView() {
        delegate?.detailViewDidChange()
    }
}
```

Now in the tableview...

```
func prepareForSegue(...) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

and...

```
extension MyTableViewController: DetailViewDelegate {
    func detailViewDidChange() {
        // respond to the change here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @hell2809 why not?

Comment: @hell2809 why is this not the solution? You are trying to run some code in the view controller that you are going back to. Why do you think this is not the solution for doing that? If you don’t actually provide any feedback how can anyone help?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I was so busy fixing my project because of requirement changes :( turn out my customer doesn't want anything my team was building at the first place... Thanks for your time anyway, I really appreciate that!

Comment: @hell2809 no worries. I know what that's like. Good luck.